# How to dynamically set window titles in Tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to set the title of Tmux windows dynamically to the path of the first pane. How do I set a title dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so Tmux actually sets the window title based off the active pane title, you need to set the pane title and it will be used as the window title. These instructions are for fish, feel free to add examples for bash and zsh etc.

Create a new function:

```
function tmux_pane_title --on-variable PWD
    printf "\033k$PWD\033\\"
end
```

Then put this in your config.fish:

```
tmux_pane_title
```

source: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/981
source: `man tmux` NAMES AND TITLES section